# Parse and Facebook sdk 4.1 login and signup returning "User Cancelled Login" Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I recently updated my Parse SDK to **1.7.4** and `Facebook SDK` to **4.1**, but for getting user data a code that was working in Facebook SDK 3.22.2 is not working in Facebook SDK 4.1. I'm getting error:

> Unknown type name 'FBRequest'; did you mean 'SKRequest'?

[image: This is the screenshot]

```
- (void)requestFacebook:(PFUser *)user
{
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
         [self processFacebook:user UserData:userData];
     }
     else
     {
         [PFUser logOut];
         [ProgressHUD showError:@"Failed to fetch Facebook user data."];
     }
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help after verificationwith de link, my i changed my code into this one and worked fine but in iOS 8.1 it's no etch Facebook user data

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                               parameters:nil];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
         [self processFacebook:user UserData:userData];
     }
     else
     {
         [PFUser logOut];
         [ProgressHUD showError:@"Failed to fetch Facebook user data."];
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The new Facebook SDK 4.x is now divided into 3 main parts: `FBSDKCoreKit`, `FBSDKLoginKit` and `FBSDKShareKit`.
The new SDK has replaced `FBRequest` with `FBSDKGraphRequest` and `FBSDKGraphRequestConnection` which are in `FBSDKCoreKit`. Import this into your code and modify your implementation accordingly. You can see an example of how to use the new classes [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x#graph).